# Promise.all is finished before the promises that it's relying on

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a list of API requests that only when all of them are finished I will return an answer. I used th Promise.all for that but it seems like the then of promise.all is being triggered before the promises he suppose to wait for.
I figured it happens because I have an get request inside of a post request. How can I make this work?

This a react-redux prject.

```
if (devices) {
    const APIArray = [];
    devices.forEach(device => {
        const data = {
            id: device.id,
        };
        dispatch({ type: EDIT_DEVICE, payload: data });
        APIArray.push(
            axios
                .post('/deploy/update', data)
                .then(res => {
                    ApiUtils.get(`/deploy/device?deviceId=${data.id}`).then(response => {
                        console.log('1');
                        dispatch({ type: EDIT_DEVICE_SUCCESS, payload: { device: response.data } });
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    dispatch({ type: EDIT_DEVICE_FAIL, payload: { device: data, error: error } });
                })
        );
    });

    return Promise.all(APIArray)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('2');
            dispatch({ type: UPDATE_DEVICES_SUCCESS, payload: res });
            return res;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err
        );
}

expected: console.log('1')
          console.log('1')
          console.log('2')
actual: console.log('2')
        console.log('1')
        console.log('1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the inner promise to the outer chain:

```
 return ApiUtils.get(`/deploy/device?deviceId=${data.id}`).then(/*...*/);
```

By returning it, the promise returned by the outer `.then` will be chained of that.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the promises are the ones returned by Axios.post, but once you receive the post result you do another get into another promise.

```
APIArray.push(
        axios
            .post('/deploy/update', data)
            .then(res => {
                return ApiUtils.get(`/deploy/device?deviceId=${data.id}`).then(response => {
                    console.log('1');
                    dispatch({ type: EDIT_DEVICE_SUCCESS, payload: { device: response.data } });
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch({ type: EDIT_DEVICE_FAIL, payload: { device: data, error: error } });
            })
    );
```

See in the then, I have added a return statement. That way the ApiUtils.get promise gets passed to the promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
.then(res => {
   ApiUtils.get(`/deploy/device?deviceId=${data.id}`).then(...);
})
```

by

```
.then(res => {
   return ApiUtils.get(`/deploy/device?deviceId=${data.id}`).then(...);
 })

 // or without brackets

.then(res => ApiUtils.get(`/deploy/device?deviceId=${data.id}`).then(...))
```